# React component is not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a problem. So, I'm making react component and I need tooltip with button. Tooltip is working, but I can't place it where I want(I mean in the centre of the button and above that).

When I consoled log that, it's showing mne that e.target.offsetLeft and e.target.offsetTop are 0, but I gave it margin from both sides.

But actually when I place this code which have to place tooltip, then whole tooltip is not displayed:

```
tooltip.style.left = options.x + (options.w / 2) - (tooltip.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
tooltip.style.top = (options.y - tooltip.offsetHeight - 10) + "px";
```

And it's my whole code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Style from 'style-it'; 
var Ink = require('react-ink');
import FontIcon from '../FontIcon/FontIcon';

var IconButton = React.createClass({

getInitialState() {
  return {
      iconStyle: "",
      style: "",
      cursorPos: {},
  };
},

render() {

var _props = this.props,

...

  globalTooltip = null,

...

function createTooltip(options) {
  var tooltip = document.createElement("div");

  tooltip.className = "tooltip";
  tooltip.appendChild(document.createTextNode(_props.tooltip));
  document.body.appendChild(tooltip);

  tooltip.style.left = options.x + (options.w / 2) - (tooltip.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
  tooltip.style.top = (options.y - tooltip.offsetHeight - 10) + "px";

  globalTooltip = tooltip;

  console.log(options);

};

function showTooltip(e){

  var options = {
    w: e.target.offsetWidth,
    x: e.target.offsetLeft,
    y: e.target.offsetTop,
  };


  createTooltip(options);

};

function removeTooltip(e){
  globalTooltip.parentNode.removeChild(globalTooltip);
};

    return(
...
    );

    }});

ReactDOM.render(
<IconButton ... tooltip="aaaaa" />, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And at this moment I can't even console log the options object :/

Comment: You could as well just show/hide tooltip element using `display` CSS property set either to `none` or `block` based on component's props. It would even work faster than updating DOM.

Comment: upvoted for @free-soul 's answer, it's better to do it by the ReactJS way.

Comment: it's working very well, but I can't place this where I want it to be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a fix to the bug in your code, but I'm outlining some React principles and features that will help you solve your problems with just React (instead of mixing native DOM APIs and React APIs).

It is not advised to directly access the DOM elements using native DOM APIs when you are using React. Handling DOM is the job of React. That is what React is for. So if you modify/remove/insert elements from/into elements created using React, you are losing the whole advantage of that powerful library; **minimal DOM change**.

In simple words, if we modify the DOM elements created by React, and when React comes back and looks again to the DOM for performing its diffing algorithm, it is now something else, someone has altered it without React's knowledge; and React gets confused. Thus **React fails do its optimization magics for what it is famous for.**

To handle DOM nodes, React has a feature called [**`Refs`**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), which are essentially references to original DOM nodes. But you need to define it if you want to use it.

Example usage of `ref`:

```
class AutoFocusTextInput extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.textInput.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} />
    );
  }
}
```

In the above example, if you want the `offsetWidth`, `offsetHeight` or any other DOM properties of `<input>` element, you can access it by `this.textInput.offsetWidth`, `this.textInput.offsetHeight` etc. But treat them as read-only.

If you want to alter the styles:
add a `style` attribute to the element in your JSX and modify the inline styles using [React State and Lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

```
<input
    style={{ left: this.state.offsetTop, top: this.state.offsetTop }}
    ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
/>
```

I also saw in your code that you're using `.removeChild` and `.appendChild` in order to hide/show tooltip. Instead of that make use of [React's Conditional Rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

example:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.showToolTip ? <Tooltip ... /> : null}

            {/* ... other stuff ... */}
        </div>
    );    
}
```

If we are using React, then we should use it for a purpose, rather than just to say we are using it.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, I'm still learning React and thanks for the tips, I'll definitely check all of these and learn that. And I have purpose, but it's still a long way before me to be as good as you. Once again, big thanks :)